# how to print request both modelname and districtname in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

working with laravel 5.6 and mysql. I have following table name as `vehicles`

```
id  name  categoryname  brandname    model     districtname
1   juy   car           toyota       121       coba
2   gty   van           nissan       caravan   natai
3   bgh   car           bmw          520d      zenso
4   hyu   van           ford         max       mizuri
5   nhj   car           toyota       121       nakaga
6   gtr   car           toyota       corolla   wassa
7   gtr   van           nissan       caravan   goa
```

I have following controller function to filter request modelname,

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')
                ->when(request('modelname'), function ($query, $request) {
                    return $query->where('modelname', request('modelname'));
                })
                ->orderBy('adtype','DESC')
```

and My blade link to display above data is,

```
<a href="{{ route('vehicles.modelindex') }}?modelname={{$dis->modelname}}{{$dis->modelname}}</a>
```

and route

```
Route::get('modelname', [
    'uses' => 'VehicleController@indexmodel',
    'as'   => 'vehicles.modelindex',

]);
```

but now I need filter districtname also with modelname and then I change my blade link as

```
<a href="{{ route('vehicles.modelindex') }}?modelname={{$dis->modelname}}?districtname={{$dis->districtname}}">{{$dis->modelname}}</a>
```

and controller like

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')
                ->when(request('modelname'), function ($query, $request) {
                    return $query->where('modelname', request('modelname'));
                })
                ->when(request('districtname'), function ($query, $request) {
                    return $query->where('districtname',request('districtname'));
                })


            ->orderBy('adtype','DESC')
```

but now when I click above new link url like this
`http://localhost:8000/modelname?modelname=Highlander%20Hybrid?districtname=newyork`

but not displaying any results. results showing blade view is,

```
 @forelse( $vehicles as $vehicule )

@if( $vehicule->uploads->count() > 0 )
                        <a href="{{ route('vehicles.show', $vehicule->id) }}">
                            @php
                                $upload = $vehicule->uploads->sortByDesc('id')->first();
                            @endphp
                           Vehicle Model Name: {{$vehicule->modelname}}
                            <div style="border-style: solid; background-color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? '#FFEFD5' : '#FFFFFF' }} ">
                            <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" height="150" width="250"></a>


                       <label> {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($vehicule->created_at)->diffForHumans()}} </label>
                         <label>  {{$vehicule->provincename}}</label>
                         <label> {{$vehicule->milage}}</label>
                        @endif

            @empty
                <td>Sorry,No Advertisment to display.</td>
            @endforelse
```

but when click new link with model name and district name page displaying only `Sorry,No Advertisment to display`

how can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I can notice is the way you built your get request. If you append parameters to a request, the first parameter is concatenated using `?` but for every following one you should use `&`.

So your URL should be like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('vehicles.modelindex') }}?modelname={{$dis->modelname}}&districtname={{$dis->districtname}}">{{$dis->modelname}}</a>
```